# Background attachment "fixed" doesn`t work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background, background-image, fixed

I find issue with background attachment in firefox.
I want to make my banner background fixed ( http://inkerkam.so-use.ru/ ), but it doesn`t work in firefox: background displayed, but it scrolls, however in chrome it works normally. And another moment, in another block below '.content' it works normally too.

my html:

```
    <div class="banner">
    ...
    </div>
...

    <div class="content">
    ....
    </div>
```

my css:

```
.banner {
    background: url(/template/img/banner.jpg) no-repeat fixed left top;
}

.content {
    background: url(/template/img/banner.jpg) 0px -690px fixed;
    padding: 80px 0 120px 0;
}
```

Maybe somebody know how to solve this problem?
Firefox version is the last one. Updates today.

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Welcome to SO, please can you create a [MCVE] in the question itself. [Please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: the problem is not with the CSS instead with the JS, owl-carousel used in the banner is creating the problem. i checked disabling it, and the background works fine. check with your JS, there must be something missing. or you can do something as @Pete mentioned so we can help.

Comment: @Lucian thx for comment, i`ll look for it

Comment: `background-attachment` isn't a great choice for parallax because it's not supported on a lot of mobile browsers and it also causes a repaint on every frame. A better choice (if your layout will allow it) is `perspective` and `translateZ`. See: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/performant-parallaxing for more detail

Answer (score 0):

Even without having the rest of the code I am almost certain that the problem is a `transform:translate` property either in the element with the background or a parent element.  When this property is applied - for any axis, either `X`, `Y` or `Z`, `background-attachment:fixed` is disabled.